# PayPal Tracking showing INVALID_TRACKING_CODE

Tags: python, paypal, python-requests, paypal-rest-sdk

Looks like I'm doing just about everything correct but I keep receiving this error....

Response text error:

`response .text {"name":"INVALID_TRACKING_NUMBER","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","debug_id":"12345","details":[{"field":"tracker_id","value":"1234-567890","location":"path","issue":"INVALID_TRACKING_INFO"}],"links":[]}`

Response status: `<Response [404]>`

I'm using a real transaction and a real tracking number.

I'm doing this through python and this is my code:

```
def paypal_oauth():
    url = 'https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
    }
    auth = "1234-1234","0987"
    data = {"grant_type":"client_credentials"}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=(auth))
    return response

def paypal_tracking(paypal_transaction_token, tracking_number, status, carrier):
    try:
        _paypal_oauth = paypal_oauth()
        _paypal_oauth_response = _paypal_oauth.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

    access_token = _paypal_oauth_response['access_token']
    url = 'https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers/%s-%s/' % (paypal_transaction_token, tracking_number)
    # https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers/1234-567890/
    carrier = carrier_code(carrier)
    # This grabs carrier from a method and gets back:  'DHL'

    headers = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % access_token,
    }
    # {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer 1234'}

    data = {
        "transaction_id":"%s" % paypal_transaction_token,
        "tracking_number":"%s" % tracking_number,
        "status": "%s" % status,
        "carrier": "%s" % carrier
    }
    # {'transaction_id': '1234', 'tracking_number': '567890', 'status': 'SHIPPED', 'carrier': 'DHL'}

    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Anyone with experience in paypal or using API's see my issue?

Comment: Have you previously added that tracking number to that transaction ID, or not? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/#add-tracking-information-with-tracking-numbers

Comment: No it's a tracking number for the order but it isn't on paypal so there shouldn't be any conflict.  I've read that page over 15 times and cannot figure out what my issue is

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to Add tracking, not update it.  I assume its PUTS because its the same model?

Answer (score 0):

To add a tracking number (not update), use an HTTP POST request, [as documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/tracking/integrate/#add-tracking-information-with-tracking-numbers).

The URL to POST to is `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers-batch` , with no additional URL parameters.

The body format is

```
{
  "trackers": [
    {
      "transaction_id": "8MC585209K746392H",
      "tracking_number": "443844607820",
      "status": "SHIPPED",
      "carrier": "FEDEX"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "53Y56775AE587553X",
      "tracking_number": "443844607821",
      "status": "SHIPPED",
      "carrier": "FEDEX"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that `trackers` is an *array* of JSON *object(s)*.